# How to speed up compilation of 30+ languages ASP.NET Web Site in VS.NET 2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, translation, asp.net-4.0

Recently, I added a massive amount of new languages (as RESX files) to an ASP.NET Web Site project in VS.NET 2010.

The project has approximately 50 ASPX pages and did build rather fast, before I added the languages.

Since the languages were added the compiler takes several minutes (well, at least 1-2) until the browser sees a page.

Now I'm currently investigating, whether I could speed up compilation time inside my development environment. I can think of:

- Leaving out the RESX files in VS.NET and copy them from another, external folder, when deploying to the web server, only.
- Change the project type from Web Site to [Web Application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/08/VS-2005-Web-Application-Project-V1.0-Released.aspx).

**My question:**

Can you give me some advices on how you would improve development speed of a large multi-language website in ASP.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your resources in a [precompiled assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx). This should significantly cut down your dynamic compile times, which is the default behavior for ASP.NET.

In the development environment, it would only recompile that assembly when there were changes which would obviously necessitate a rebuild of the assembly.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Do you have any entry points on how to start? (I found no resource-specific information in the link you provided) Maybe there is an example proof-of-concept project?

Comment: Try this project http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/06/05/asp.net-localization-enabling-resource-expressions-with-an-external-resource-assembly.aspx